# MySQL “Unknown Column in On Clause” when selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, string, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
select film.title, film_actor.film_id, count(*) as castAmount, concat(actor.first_name, ' ', 
actor.last_name) as actorFullName

from film, actor

inner join film_actor on film_actor.film_id = film.film_id 

group by film.film_id
```

I am receiving the error: unknown column 'film.film_id' in 'on clause'
I have read it has to do with multiple join statements but am having a hard time finding a solution that gives me the correct results. I want to concatenate first_name and last_name as actorFullName, where the first and last name are grabbed from the 'actor' table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix implicit and explicit joins! Use standard, explicit joins consistently.

Your query is also inconsistent in terms of aggregation. If you want one row per film (as your current `group by` clause indicates), then you need to aggregate the actor names.

You might be looking for:

```
select f.title, f.film_id, count(*) as castAmount,
    group_concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) actor_full_names
from film_actor fa
inner join film  f on f.film_id  = fa.film_id 
inner join actor a on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
group by f.film_id
```

This generates one row per film, along with the count of actors, and the list of actor full names, separated by commas.